# DB Architecture question: Would using a JSONB column for storing row changes be an efficient solution?

Tags: postgresql

I have an app which allows for dynamic table and column generation. One feature we are looking to implement is change tracking for each row. Anytime any changes occur, we want to keep track of the field and what the new value is.

One potential solution we are looking at is adding a "history" JSONB column to the table which would contain an ongoing array of every change. When a field is updated or multiple fields are updated, we could append a new element to the history field by using the || append syntax which will append the element to the existing jsonb vlaue:

update table set history = history || '{new node with changes}'

When viewing the "history changes", it would all be contained in this JSONB field and we'd have logic to parse out /display the changes over time.

Note: We won't need to query this JSONB column. It's simply the place to store all the row level changes. It seems like this should be an efficient way of saving updates.

My question is, is this a viable solution in regards to performance over time? It's possible this history field could become large over time, so would making any row changes become slower the larger the field? Or does the fact we are using the || operator to append data to the field mitigate any performance issues?

FYI, I am currently on Postgres 11, but could upgrade to newer versions if that had an impact.

Thanks for any feedback you can provide.

Comment: I would rather recommend to store the history events in a separate table (and one row per change), not as a huge array inside the original row. Yes, I would expect a huge field to slow down updates, it would have to be copied over every time.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. Would it be ok to store the change itself as a JSONB field? So, each change would be a new row, but the change, which could be an array of field,value updates as a json object.

Comment: Yes, "a change record containing arbitrary fields" sounds like a perfect use case for JSONB.

Comment: Interesting question. Might fit better for [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com). For me, I like @bergi's suggestion of separate history table. The history table can look just like the main table with the addition of one refid column. You can make trigger functions that automatically copy data from main to history whenever there is an INSERT or UPDATE. So the upside for this approach is that column names are the same for both tables and it's easy to write queries. The downside of this approach is that it is less efficient use of disk space for large, frequently updated table.